# Type conditioned to a Generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I was wondering if something like this is possible in TypeScript:

```
type Something = {...}

interface A extends Something {...}
interface B extends Something {...}

interface MyInterface<T extends Something> {
    method(): T
    anotherMethod(): number | number[]
}
```

The type returned by `anotherMethod()` depends on the generic, meaning:

- if T is type A then `anotherMethod() => number`
- if T is type B then `anotherMethod() => number[]`

E.g.

```
const myObjA: MyInterface<A> = {}
myObjA.anotherMethod() // ==> returns a number

const myObjB: MyInterface<B> = {}
myObjB.anotherMethod() // ==> returns an array
```

Does the question make sense?

Thanks in advance,
Fran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing, you can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) for that.

```js
interface MyInterface<T extends Something> {
    method(): T
    anotherMethod(): T extends A ? number : number[]
}

declare const myObjA: MyInterface<A>
const a = myObjA.anotherMethod() // number

declare const myObjB: MyInterface<B>
const b = myObjB.anotherMethod() // number[]
```

Comment: Excellent!!, yes, this definitely answers my question. Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of conditional types.